# Создать зеркало для хоста Denwer

Tags: хосты

Хотел прикрепить к своему проекту Яндекс.Карты.Для этого нужно получить API-ключ, а для этого нужно указать корректный домен.Мой проект находится по адресу http://palitra/, а это некорректный домен, как сделать так, чтобы можно было заходить на этот же хост, под другим адресом (зеркалом), например http://maps.palitra/ без создания субдоменов, и перенесения всего проекта в другую папку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Пропишите копию VirtualHost'а сайта из vhosts.conf в httpd.conf, исправив ServerName и ServerAlias.
2. Добавьте в системный файл hosts запись "127.0.0.1       maps.palitra".

Comment: А в файле .htaccess никак ничего нельзя сделать?

Comment: Можно: если запрос приходит на palitra, то через .htaccess (или httpd.conf) можно перенаправить его на другую папку (и, кажется, проще это сделать на Unix-сервере - из-за формата пути). В данном случае, задача противоположная: создать отдельный "хост", на который будут приниматься запросы в ту же папку... Файлы httpd.conf и vhosts.conf находятся в: /usr/local/apache/conf/.